# How to generate an element on the right side of the heading with jQuery/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I need help with one of my projects. Shown here in a short code example what it is about.

Imagine that we have two areas. These are marked with the class "box". In both boxes are elements which each have a heading and a certain content. Let's limit our example to the relevant headings.

Now I would like to add elements in the right box, which are positioned directly behind the text of the headings. However, it should be noted that this element should not be a pseudo-element, because on the one hand I have already used it in my project and certain functions are called that are not intended for pseudo-elements.

How do I position an element directly behind the text of another element?

```js
generateNewItems();

function generateNewItems() {
  let elements = $(".box#test div");
  
  for (let elem of elements) {
    let heading = $(elem).children("h3");
    
    let leftPos = 10; /* HOW? */
    
    let el = $("<div>").addClass("new-item").css({
        "left": leftPos,
      "top": -3
    });
    
    $(elem).append(el);
  }
}
```

```css
.new-item {
  position:absolute;
  background:red;
  height:30px;
  width:30px;
}

.box {
  width:50%;
  background:lightblue;
  float:left;
}

.box > div {
  position:relative;
}

.box > div > h3 {
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <div>
    <h3>test-one</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
      <h3>test-two</h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="box" id="test">
  <div>
    <h3>small-text</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
      <h3>long-sample-text</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: *You aren't allowed to use pseudo-elements!* Why not?

Comment: @Michel I used them in my project already for something. If I use pseudo-elements here I have the same problem with the other elements.

Comment: So where do you want them exactly? After `test-one` and `test-two` or after `sample text` and `long sample text`?

Comment: @Michel In this example I want the red element exactly after the end of the words. In this case after sample-text and long-sample-text.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, as the `h3` elements that contain your text actually fill the parent `div`. So you can't get the **text** width, only the `h3` width that wouldn't be correct for what you want to achieve. I think you either have to change your HTML structure or change the functions that interfere with pseudo elements, and use the pseudo elements to achieve what you want

Comment: @LucaDeNardi Isn't it possible with "getBoundingClientRect()" or something like that? Maybe it is possible to calculate the text-value, isn't it?

Comment: `getBoundingCliebtRect` returns the size and position of the **occupied space** of an element. In your case, it would return the size of the `h3` (which fills the parent) and not the size of the actual text. To get the size of the text you could change the `display` to **inline-block** but this would also change the way the `h3` are displayed. Or you could wrap your texts into `span`s, that have their own size, and get their size with the `getBoundingRect` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way:

You have to add the `<span>` to the content of the `<h3>`. Give it `100% height` and  `30px width`, and make it `position: relative`.

Inside that span, put another span with `position:absolute` and give this the size and color you want.

**Note**: this works wether the text is left, center or right, but only then when the text inside the `<h1>` isn't the full width of the `<div>`

```js
generateNewItems();

function generateNewItems() {
  let elements = $(".box#test div");
  
  for (let elem of elements) {
    let heading = $(elem).children("h3");
    
    let el1 = $("<span>").addClass("new-item-fake");
    let el2 = $("<span>").addClass("new-item");
    $(el1).append(el2);
    $(heading).append(el1);

    
  }
}
```

```css
.new-item-fake {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
  height:100%;
  width:30px;

}
.new-item {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
top: -21px;
left: 0px;
  height:30px;
  width:30px;


background: red;
}

.box {
  width:50%;
  background:lightblue;
  float:left;
}

.box > div {
  position:relative;
}

.box > div > h3 {
text-align: right;
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <div>
    <h3>test-one</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
      <h3>test-two</h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="box" id="test">
  <div>
    <h3>small-text</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
      <h3>long-sample-text</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If changing your HTML structure is an option, I'd say that could enclose your texts in `span` elements, and then get their size with `getBoundingClientRect`.

Then you have to find those elements with the code

```
let heading = $(elem).find("h3 > span");
```

And you set the `left` style of the rectangles with

```
let leftPos = heading[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;
```

(`heading[0]` is used because `getBoundingClientRect` is a Javascript function, not a jQuery one)

```js
generateNewItems();

function generateNewItems() {
  let elements = $(".box#test div");
  
  for (let elem of elements) {
    let heading = $(elem).find("h3 > span");
    
    let leftPos = heading[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;
    
    let el = $("<div>").addClass("new-item").css({
        "left": leftPos,
      "top": -3
    });
    
    $(elem).append(el);
  }
}
```

```css
.new-item {
  position:absolute;
  background:red;
  height:30px;
  width:30px;
}

.box {
  width:50%;
  background:lightblue;
  float:left;
}

.box > div {
  position:relative;
}

.box > div > h3 {
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <div>
  <h3><span>test-one</span></h3>
  </div>
  <div>
  <h3><span>test-two</span></h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="box" id="test">
  <div>
  <h3><span>small-text</span></h3>
  </div>
  <div>
  <h3><span>long-sample-text</span></h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this fails with `text-align: right` as then the red boxes will be outside the container box. Fails also with `text-align: center` when resizing the window. That's the crappy thing with positioning trough javascript, you always have to recalc.